# PostgreSQL there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am creating a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE artist (
    Id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    NameNormalized varchar(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name text NOT NULL,
    MusicBrainzId char(36) NULL,
    Rating DECIMAL(2,1),
    CONSTRAINT non_empty CHECK (length(NameNormalized) > 0 and length(Name) > 0)
);
```

When I try to execute the following INSERT operation, I get an error:

```sql
INSERT INTO artist (NameNormalized, Name, MusicBrainzId, Rating)
VALUES ('test', 'Test', '123456789012345678901234567890123456', 0.5)
ON CONFLICT (NameNormalized) DO NOTHING;
```

The error message is as follows:

```
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

I have done some research but to my knowledge, setting NameNormalized to UNIQUE should be enough for ON CONFLICT to work. Also I am pretty sure this has worked in the past for me.

Comment: you probably connect to different db or use dofferent schema?

Comment: Okay, it was actually an error with my docker configuration and had nothing to do with postgresql.